# How to prove Riemann curvature identities

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

Let $R_{abcd}$ be the Riemann curvature with all indices lowered. It is said that from the antisymmetric property $R_{abcd}=-R_{bacd}$ and the first Bianchi Identity $R_{abcd}+R_{acdb}+R_{adbc}=0$ it is possible to prove the symmetric property $R_{abcd}=R_{cdab}$. But I cannot find a way to prove this. Could anyone help me?

Comment: I deleted your picture, since the result is purely algebraic.

Answer (score 10):

The symmetry $R_{abcd}=R_{cdab}$ does *not* follow from $R_{abcd}=-R_{bacd}$ and the Bianchi Identity.  You also need to assume antisymmetry in the last two indices: $R_{abcd}=-R_{abdc}$.  With that additional assumption, the proof by @caverac works.

The additional symmetry, $R_{abcd}=-R_{abdc}$, depends on the fact that the Levi-Civita connection is compatible with the metric; without this assumption, the symmetry $R_{abcd}=-R_{abdc}$ might not hold.

It's interesting to note that the three symmetries reflect different aspects of the connection:

- $R_{abcd}=-R_{bacd}$ is true for the curvature of any connection on the tangent bundle (after lowering an index with respect to any metric at all).
- $R_{abcd}=-R_{abdc}$ follows from compatibility of $\nabla$ with the metric, as noted above.
- The Bianchi identity $R_{abcd} + R_{bcad} + R_{cabd}=0$ follows from the fact that the connection is torsion-free.
- $R_{abcd}=R_{cdab}$ follows from the three symmetries above.

(This Bianchi identity is slightly different from the one you wrote, because it involves the two indices that are independently known to be antisymmetric.) See pages 121-123 in my [*Riemannian Manifolds*](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387982717) for more detail.

Comment: Very interesting, specially your second bullet point ... I completely overlooked that. I will leave my answer since I believe it complements yours. Thanks! (+1)

Answer (score 3):

$\require{cancel}$

I will call BI: Bianchi Identity, and SS: Skew Symmetry, so that

\begin{eqnarray}
R_{abcd} - R_{cdab} &\stackrel{\rm BI}{=}& R_{abcd} - (-R_{cabd} - R_{cbda})\\
&\stackrel{\rm SS}{=}& R_{abcd} - R_{acbd} - R_{bcda}  \\
&\stackrel{\rm BI}{=}& R_{abcd} - (-R_{abdc} - R_{adcb}) - (- R_{bacd} - R_{bdac}) \\
&=& R_{abcd} + R_{abdc} + R_{adcb} + R_{bacd} + R_{bdac} \\
&\stackrel{\rm SS}{=}& \cancel{R_{abcd}}- \cancel{R_{abcd}} + R_{adcb} - R_{abcd} + R_{bdac} \\
&=& -R_{abcd} + R_{adcb} + R_{bdac} \\
&\stackrel{\rm SS}{=}& -(R_{abcd} - R_{adbc}) + R_{bdac} \\
&\stackrel{\rm BI}{=}&  R_{acdb} + R_{bdac} \\
&\stackrel{\rm SS}{=}& -R_{acbd} + R_{bdac} \tag{1}
\end{eqnarray}

Now, I'm going to change the *name* of the indices $a\leftrightarrow b$ and $c\leftrightarrow d$

\begin{eqnarray}
R_{badc} - R_{dcba} &=& -R_{bdac} + R_{acbd} \\
R_{abcd} - R_{cdab} &\stackrel{\rm SS}{=}&  -R_{bdac} + R_{acbd}\\
&\stackrel{(1)}{=}&-R_{acbd}+R_{bdac} \tag{2}
\end{eqnarray}

From the last identity we have then

$$
-R_{bdac} + R_{acbd} = -R_{acbd}+R_{bdac} \tag{3}
$$

which leads to

$$
R_{bdac} = R_{acbd}
$$

... and that's it

Comment: There's a mistake in your computation. The OP wanted to prove that $R_{abcd}=R_{cdab}$ follows just from antisymmetry in the first two indices and the Bianchi identity. But in your computation (1) above, you used antisymmetry in the _last two_ indices, which does not follow from the given assumptions. See my answer to this question.